# Apply variable to button in view from controller?Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, view, sencha-touch, extjs

So I have the view below. This view is called when an item from a list on a previous view is tapped.  The lists on this view are filtered based on the previous selection, but I want to be able to add items to these lists that contain the same filter (store field = "value"). How can I get it so that the value that is filtering the lists is also passed when clicking the button and loading a new view?

My View page.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.view.ShowAll", {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  requires: ['Ext.NavigationView', 'Ext.dataview.List', 'Ext.layout.HBox', 'Ext.Container'],
  xtype: 'myapp-showall',

  config: {
      layout: 'hbox',
      items: [
        {
        layout: 'fit',
      xtype: 'container',
      itemId: 'listContainer',
      flex: 1,
        items: [
         {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: 'leftStore',
            itemTpl: '{storeField}',
            emptyText: 'No values added yet'
          },
          {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            padding: '5px',
            items: [{ xtype: 'button', itemId: 'addValue', text: 'Add Values', ui: 'confirm', width:'100%' }]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        style: "background-color: #333;",
        width: 10
    },
    {
    layout: 'fit',
      xtype: 'container',
      itemId: 'listContainerTwo',
      flex: 1,
        items: [
         {
            xtype: 'list',
            store: 'rightStore',
            itemTpl: '{storeField}',
            emptyText: 'No values added yet'
          },
          {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            padding: '5px',
            items: [{ xtype: 'button', itemId: 'addValueRight', text: 'Add Values', ui: 'confirm', width:'100%' }]
          }
        ]
    }
    ]
  }
});
```

Here is part of my Controller (which sets the store filters)

```
  showValues: function() {
    this.showValueDetails(arguments[3]);
  },

  showValueDetails: function(record) { 
    var title = "Value: "+record['data']['name'];
    var showValue = Ext.create('MyApp.view.ShowAll', { title: title });
    showValue.setRecord(record);

    var valueName = record['data']['name'];
    var leftStore = Ext.getStore("leftStore"); 
    leftStore.clearFilter();
    leftStore.filter('storeField', valueName); 

    var rightStore = Ext.getStore("rightStore"); 
    rightStore.clearFilter();
    rightStore.filter('storeField', valueName); 

    this.getMain().push(showValue);

},
```

It sets the page title correctly and filters the store also. I just am unsure how to pass a variable so when the buttons are clicked the valueName (from controller) is passed to the next view.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was able to set the title fine using the code above, once I click the submit button all it takes is the following to get the title.

```
    var titleVariable = Ext.getCmp('ShowAll')['title'];
```